# Row won't move to the next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on my personal website and i'm trying to make a new row with Bootstrap 4. The row has an H1 above it. Whatever I'm trying, the row won't move to the next line. I tried different solutions, inline, br, different rows, nothing works. Can somebody help me out? 
This is my current HTML code:
    `<h1>Projecten</h1><br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">col</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col</div>
    </div>`

I didn't change anything on the CSS code, just the default bootstrap code.

[Click here for a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRekm.png)

Comment: Please include code in the question

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: add your html code

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: try the same with bootstrap3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bootstrap is

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>col</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>col</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>col</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you import and bootstrap CSS and JS?